# Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Database\DatabaseError 404 Not Found

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Laravel so i have been trying to connect Laravel to a Firebase Realtime database but i am getting this error **Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Database\DatabaseError
404 Not Found** . I have the Service account in the controllers directory and properly referenced in the Firebase controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Kreait\Firebase;

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

use Kreait\Firebase\Database;

class FirebaseController extends Controller
{
 $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/myServiceAccount.json');

$database = $factory->createDatabase();

$newPost  = $database->getReference('myrealtime-default-rtdb/blog/posts')->push(['title' => 'Post title','body' => 'This should probably be longer.']);

        echo"<pre>";
print_r($newPost->getvalue());

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the new Factory pattern won't work (it's already handled by the Laravel Service Provider).

Personally I'd recommend using the app() helper. It's quite easy but before that make sure you've followed the installation process in the documentation. You might've missed something

Here's a link to that: https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase

Also make sure you include **both** the path to your Service Account json file and the database URL for your project in your .env file (I prefer using this method personally)

So in your .env file you should have something like

FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS = path_to_your_service_account_file.json

FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL= https://your-project-url.firebaseio.com/
(you can find this url when you open RealTime databases in your firebase console)

If you don't use auto-discovery make sure to add   Kreait\Laravel\Firebase\ServiceProvider::class to your providers in the config/app.php file

run a vendor publish

Then in your controller you could have something like this

> namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> class FirebaseController extends Controller {
> //
>
> ```
> protected $database;
>
> public function __construct()
> {
>     $this->database = app('firebase.database');
>
> }
>
> public function index(){
>     $new_post = $this->database->getReference('your-reference')>push(["title" =>"something"]);
> } }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Remember: on Linux, place Firebase config files etc. in a folder that user 'apache' can read! So, for example, do not place such files in `/home/myname/firebase.json`. Even if you do `chmod 777 firebase.json`, this file may not be accessible by user 'apache', hence the 404.

Then you do not need to use env variables.

```
$factory = (new Factory())->withServiceAccount(DIR.'/vendor/firebase-adminsdk.json');
```